# React Native StackNavigator initialRouteName with parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In 'react-navigation' library, How can I send the parameters with initialRouteName in Stack.Navigator.

```
 return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName={routeName}
      screenOptions={{
        animation: 'slide_from_right',
      }}>
```

This is the return of my navigation file and I'm setting the routeName dynamically but the screen on which I want to initially route must need route parameters to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can utilize the prop "initialParams" that can be added to your screen component

```
<Screen 
   initialParams={{id:0}}
   {...otherScreenProps}
/>
```

you can also handle it with a condition like `initialParams={initialRouteName === screenName ? {id:0} : undefined}`

I believe there are other options like setParams, but i'm unsure of your exact use case

Comment: Thanks, my use case is I'm listening on fcm notifications and navigate to specific screen  on click of the notification..

Comment: So you wanna navigate to a specific screen in your app, when pressing the notification from outside (or inside) the app? if that's the case then i suggest that you take a look at Deep Linking https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/ and https://medium.com/knock-engineering/react-native-push-notification-deep-links-5d0aa0375f2

Comment: If that's the case then you don't need to dynamically set the initial route, but the setup might be a little tedious

Comment: yes sure I'm on to deep linking..
Thanku

Comment: with deep linking I'm able to navigate properly but the issue is that my navigated screen don't have the bottom navigation which is defined in separate HomeScreen

Comment: in that case you might wanna take a look on how to navigate "Nested Navigators" with deep linking, sadly i don't have a code snippet for that but it's most likely related to how you structure and navigate nested navigators

Answer (score 0):

you can pass params as below.
 `initialParams={{ itemId: 42 }}`

These `initialParams` props are provided by react-navigation, you can use that initially.

also whenever you setparams from the specific screen you can use the code below.

```
navigation.setParams({
  itemId: {set your dynamic value},
});
```

for the reference :-
[click here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)